# Match legend and Plot size

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot, mathematica-8

Please Consider :

```
intense = Reverse[Round[Rationalize /@ N[10^Range[0, 3, 1/3]]]];
values = Range[0, 9/10, 1/10];

intensityLegend = Column[Prepend[MapThread[
                         Function[{intensity, values},
                         Row[{Graphics[{(Lighter[Blue, values]),
                         Rectangle[{0, 0}, {4, 1}], Black, 
                         Text[Style[ToString[intensity], 16, Bold], {2, .5}]}]}]],
                        {intense, values}], Text[Style["Photons Number", Bold, 15]]]];

IntersectionDp1={{1., 588.377}, {2.15443, 580.306}, {4.64159, 573.466}, {10.,560.664}, 
                 {21.5443, 552.031}, {46.4159, 547.57}, {100.,545.051}, 
                 {215.443, 543.578}, {464.159, 542.281}, {1000., 541.346}}


FindD1=ListLogLinearPlot[Map[List, IntersectionDp1], 
                  Frame -> True, 
                  AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, 
                  PlotMarkers -> 
                  With[{markerSize = 0.04}, {Graphics[{Lighter[Blue, #], Disk[]}], 
                       markerSize} & /@Range[9/10, 0, -1/10]], Filling -> Axis, 
                  FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.8], 
                  PlotRange -> {{.5, 1100}, {540, 600}},
                  ImageSize->400];

Grid[{{intensityLegend, FindD1}, {intensityLegend, FindD1}}, 
      ItemSize -> {50, 20}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**How could I get the legend Column Size to Fit the Height of the Plot Area ?**

While Row adjust the size I need to use Grid. This is why I duplicated in grid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Working with Image Sizes. The (* <- *) marks the important modifications to your code, the rest are mainly font size thingies:

```
intense = Reverse[Round[Rationalize /@ N[10^Range[0, 3, 1/3]]]];
values = Range[0, 9/10, 1/10];
imgSize = 400;                                                          (* <- *) 
Off[Ticks::ticks]

IntersectionDp1 =  {{1., 588.377},     {2.15443, 580.306}, {4.64159, 573.466}, 
   {10., 560.664}, {21.5443, 552.031}, {46.4159, 547.57},  {100., 545.051},
   {215.443, 543.578}, {464.159, 542.281}, {1000., 541.346}}

FindD1 = ListLogLinearPlot[Map[List, IntersectionDp1], Frame -> True, 
   AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, 
   PlotMarkers -> 
    With[{markerSize = 0.04}, 
     {Graphics[{Lighter[Blue, #], Disk[]}], markerSize} & 
       /@ Range[9/10, 0, -1/10]], Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.8], 
       PlotRange -> {{.5, 1100}, {540, 600}}, ImageSize -> imgSize];    (* <- *) 

intensityLegend =
  Rasterize[Column[
    Prepend[
     Reverse@MapThread[                                                 (* <- *) 
      Function[{intensity, values}, 
       Row[{Graphics[{(Lighter[Blue, values]), 
           Rectangle[{0, 0}, {4, 1}], Black, 
           Text[Style[ToString[intensity], 30, Bold], {2, .5}]}]}]],
      {intense, values}],
     Text[Style["Photons Number", Bold, 25]]]], 
   ImageSize -> {Automatic,                                             (* <- *) 
     IntegerPart@                            
      First[imgSize Cases[AbsoluteOptions[FindD1], 
         HoldPattern[AspectRatio -> x_] -> x]]}];

Grid[{{intensityLegend, FindD1}, {intensityLegend, FindD1}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Where I reversed the intensities column for aesthetic purposes.

**Edit**

If you don't explicitly specify the ImageSize option for the Plot, you'll disappointingly find that `AbsoluteOptions[Plot,  "ImageSize"]` returns `"Automatic"` !

**Edit**  Answering the @500's comment bellow

The expression:

```
   ImageSize -> {Automatic,                                             (* <- *) 
     IntegerPart@                            
      First[imgSize Cases[AbsoluteOptions[FindD1], 
         HoldPattern[AspectRatio -> x_] -> x]]}];
```

is really a working replacement for something that *should* work **but doesn't** to get the image size of a Plot:

```
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, Last@AbsoluteOptions[FindD1,"ImageSize"]}
```

So, what the `IntegerPart[...]` thing is doing is getting the vertical size of the plot image, multiplying `imgSize` by the `AspectRatio` of the Plot.
To understand how it works, run the code and then type:

```
AbsoluteOptions[FindD1]
```

and you will see the Plot options there. Then the Cases[] function is just extracting the `AspectRatio` option.

In fact there is a cleaner way to do what the Cases[] does. It is:

```
AbsoluteOptions[FindD1,"AspectRatio"]
```

but there is another bug in the AbsoluteOptions function that prevents us to use it this way.

Comment: could you explain the following part ? I think it adapt the y size of the legend conditionally to the plot itself but I don`t understand this part: IntegerPart@
 First[imgSize Cases[AbsoluteOptions[FindD1], 
    HoldPattern[AspectRatio -> x_] -> x]]

Answer (score 4):

How about making the legend a bit smaller?

```
intensityLegend = 
  Column[Prepend[
    MapThread[
     Function[{intensity, values}, 
      Row[{Graphics[{(Lighter[Blue, values]), 
          Rectangle[{0, 0}, {4, 1}], Black, 
          Text[Style[ToString[intensity], 12, Bold], {2, .5}]}, 
         ImageSize -> 50]}]], {intense, values}], 
    Text[Style["Photons Number", Bold, 15]]]];
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much ! But I must admit I can`t get a grasp of neither Unit or Scaled yet :-) So it remains magic. I wish we were always be speaking about pixels in all case !