# Adding a Legend to a semilog plot in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot, legend

I am having trouble with the plotting functions in Mathematica. 
I am attempting to plot several lists of data on a semilog plot, and then add a legend. The plot is fine:

[image]

```
Show[ListLogPlot[bead31, PlotStyle -> Black, 
  PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSmallSquare]"}], 
 ListLogPlot[bead27, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSmallSquare]"}], 
 ListLogPlot[A5, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSmallSquare]"}], 
 ListLogPlot[A10, PlotStyle -> Green, 
  PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSmallSquare]"}], 
 ListLogPlot[A20, PlotStyle -> Gray, 
  PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSmallSquare]"}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Subscript[t, norm], \[Kappa]}, RotateLabel -> False, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

However, any attempts to add a legend either fail, or are placed in the same scale - and since its a semilog plot, all I see is a line for a legend.

I tried to create my legend separately as a Graphics object:

[image]

but I can't figure out how to place it in the image (I was playing with Inset[] and Epilog[], but I think I'm using them wrong).

```
Show[Graphics[
  Legend[{{Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}], 
     "31 beads"}, {Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}], 
     "27 beads"},
    {Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}], "A5"},
    {Graphics[{Green, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}], "A10"},
    {Graphics[{Gray, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}], "A20"}}]]]
```

If anyone knows of a way to add a legend properly into the first graph, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/7788587/353410

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
ListLogPlot[{
  Table[PartitionsQ[n], {n, 50}], 
  Table[{n, n!}, {n, 1, 20, .1}]}, 
    PlotLegend -> {"Parts", "Fact"}, LegendPosition -> {0.8, -0.8}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that works! I kept trying to add the PlotLegend command outside, in a Show command. Thanks for the help!